# How to glm on a linear model?

Tags: r, glm

```
null <- glm(Status ~ Idade, family = "binomial", data = train_data)
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = Status ~ Age, data = train_data,  : 
>     variable lengths differ (found for 'Age')

When I run `glm` I get no errors. All the variables are in a single dataset and there are no missing values. I divided de file in:

```
dim(train_data)
dim(test_data)
```

The error only occurs when i use the `train_data` and the `test_data`. When I use the whole file, I don't have errors.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid we can't answer this without a [mcve] ...

Comment: it's also **very** weird that you have a different response variable listed in your error message (`Age`) from the one shown in your code (`Idade`) ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you use anything like

```
attach(data)
```

If so, your response Status would be based on the full dataset.